# MPAndroidChart BarChart - ValueFormatter is not applied

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I use `MPAndroid` to use Group Bar chart.

I create `ValueFormatter`.

```
val StepValueFormatter = object : ValueFormatter() {
    override fun getFormattedValue(
        value: Float,
        entry: Entry?,
        dataSetIndex: Int,
        viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler?
    ): String {
        var oneText = value.toInt() * 1000
        var decimal = DecimalFormat("#,###")
        var twoText = decimal.format(oneText)

        return "${twoText} 걸음"
    }
}
```

And I applied this ValueFormatter to `BarDataSet`.

```
var bds1 = BarDataSet(entryOne, "기준")
bds1.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
bds1.valueTextSize = 16f
bds1.valueTypeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
bds1.valueTextColor = Color.BLACK
bds1.valueFormatter = StepValueFormatter
```

However BarChart graph value format is not changed.
What is the problem here?
Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getFormattedValue` overloading you're using is deprecated.
Please use the one that accepts a `float` value:

```
val StepValueFormatter = object : ValueFormatter() {
    override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
        val oneText = value.toInt() * 1000
        val decimal = DecimalFormat("#,###")
        val twoText = decimal.format(oneText)

        return "${twoText} 걸음"
    }
}
```